# CSS border-image gradient on border-left-image and border-right-image mixed with border-color

Tags: css, border-image, css-gradients

The `border-top-color` is `#9b9c9d` and the `border-bottom-color` is `#f6f9fc`. The gradients are *intended* to transition the top color to the bottom color on the `border-left` and `border-right`.

How do I mix `border-left-image` and `border-right-image` with `border-top-color` and `border-bottom-color`?

**HTML**

```
<a class="button-style">Evil Whales</a>
```

**CSS**

```
.button-style
{
 background: linear-gradient(to bottom,
   rgba(129,232,117,1) 0%,
   rgba(129,232,117,1) 50%,
   rgba(62,179,48,1) 51%,
   rgba(62,179,48,1) 100%);

 border-top-color: #9b9c9d;

 border-left-image: linear-gradient(to bottom,
   rgba(155,156,157,1) 0%,
   rgba(246,249,252,1) 100%);

 border-bottom-color: #f6f9fc;

 border-right-image: linear-gradient(to bottom,
   rgba(155,156,157,1) 0%,
   rgba(246,249,252,1) 100%);

 border-style: solid;
}
```

Comment: Please add a starting point in code.

Answer (score 1):

You can stack two gradients and use `background-size`, `padding` and `background-clip` to draw the `border`:

```css
.button-style {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(129, 232, 117, 1) 0%, rgba(129, 232, 117, 1) 50%, rgba(62, 179, 48, 1) 51%, rgba(62, 179, 48, 1) 100%) no-repeat
  /* use for background */
  , linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(155, 156, 157, 1) 0%, rgba(246, 249, 252, 1) 100%)
  /* use for border */
  ;
  background-size: 100% 100%, auto auto;
  background-clip: content-box, border-box;
  padding: 3px;
}
html {
  padding: 3em;
  background: gray;
```

```html
<a class="button-style">Evil Whales</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work though just in Chrome, Firefox and IE aren't working.

```
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,
  rgba(129,232,117,1) 0%,
  rgba(129,232,117,1) 50%,
  rgba(62,179,48,1) 51%,
  rgba(62,179,48,1) 100%);
border-image: linear-gradient(to bottom,
  rgba(155,156,157,1) 0%,
  rgba(246,249,252,1) 100%) 25 30 10 20 repeat;
border-image-repeat: stretch;
border-width: 4px;
```

It should be noted that there is no `border-left-image` and related properties; unfortunately not one of the better documented CSS properties.

Comment: When using `border-image` you use the same image for all 4 borders. It is mainly intended for cases like a picture image. However, several effects can be achieved using the additional properties. (slice, width, outset and repeat).